# How can I remove the Ubuntu option on boot loader?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu along side windows but I decided to delete ubuntu completely. I have deleted all files related to ubuntu but it still appears on boot up when I hold F10 on boot up.

**UBUNTU DOES NOT APPEAR ON BCDEDIT ON COMMAND PROMPT**

Please suggest a successful solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you removed Ubuntu, but it looks like you did not remove/replace grub, the bootloader.

Have a google around for the exact details, but in essence you need to boot from your windows cd, enter a repair console and run fixmbr.

Here is a link to one web site showing a way to it

https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/

...there are hundreds of others.